# How to fix `path must be a string` when using gulp, gulp-babel and browserify?

Tags: gulp, browserify, babeljs

I am trying to use ES2015 on my browser and then use gulp to convert it to something that browsers can understand. However, I am getting a `path must be a string` when running `gulp js` task.

`gulpfile.babel.js`

```
import Browserify from 'browserify';
import Gulp from 'gulp';
import Babel from 'gulp-babel';
import Buffer from 'vinyl-buffer';
import Source from 'vinyl-source-stream';
import Uglify from 'gulp-uglify';

Gulp.task('js', () => {
    Browserify({
        entries: 'public/scripts/Main.js',
        debug: true
    }).transform(Babel({
            presets: ['es2015-node6']
        }))
        .bundle()
        .on('error', error => console.error(error))
        .pipe(Source('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(Buffer())
        .pipe(Uglify())
        .pipe(Gulp.dest('dist/scripts/'));
});
```

Complete error message

```
{ Error: path must be a string
    at /Users/user/Documents/test/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:16:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    ...
}
```

I have tried using `babelify` instead of `gulp-babel`, however I cannot use `gulp-uglify` as I am also getting an error

```
message: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ())
```

If it matters, this is what is inside my `main.js`

```
import * as Render from './render';

(() => {
    function init () {
        console.log('here');
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
            init();
        }
    });
})();
```

and in my `render.js

```
export function Render () {
    console.log('Render');
};

export function RenderPosts () {
    console.log('RenderPosts');
}
```

Also, this isn't some React project. I just want to use ES2015 on the front-end.

Comment: I don't know about gulp. But the message said that the parameter has to be a string. Not int, double or array. Show the line number where the error occurred.

Comment: There was a restriction added in Node 6, so if you have some dependencies that are older, your best bet would be updating your `package.json` to make sure all of your deps are the most recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

Your "`path must be a string`" error is because of passing a function to `.transform`.

```
import Browserify from 'browserify';
import Gulp from 'gulp';
import Babel from 'gulp-babel';
import Buffer from 'vinyl-buffer';
import Source from 'vinyl-source-stream';
import Uglify from 'gulp-uglify';

Gulp.task('js', () => {
    Browserify({
        entries: 'public/scripts/Main.js',
        debug: true
    }).transform('babelify', {
            presets: ['es2015-node6']
        })
        .bundle()
        .on('error', error => console.error(error))
        .pipe(Source('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(Buffer())
        .pipe(Uglify())
        .pipe(Gulp.dest('dist/scripts/'));
});
```

Just in case you’re not aware, `babel-preset-es2015-node6` will only work if your browser supports ES2015 natively. It’s also perfect for use with Gulp as well.